# Unexpected behaviour doing ordered insertion in array in Prolog

Tags: arrays, prolog, graph-theory

I need to implement a queue using an array that needs to be sorted ascendently. Every item is a node of a graph, that I'm exploring using A* algorithm, that is:

```
nodo(S, ListaAzioniPerS, C, S)
```

where `S` is the identifier of the node, `ListaAzioniPerS` the path to reach that node, `C` is the cost till here, `S` is its heuristic. I need to order them by the sum of `C+S` that i called `F`

To do that I'm trying to make ordered insertions through this code:

```
orderedInsert(X, [], [X]).
orderedInsert(nodo(S, ListaAzioniPerS, C, S),
              [nodo(S1, ListaAzioniPerS1, C1, S1)|Rest],
              [nodo(S, ListaAzioniPerS, C, S), nodo(S1, ListaAzioniPerS1, C1, S1)|Rest]) :-
  F is C + S,
  F1 is C1 + S1,
  F < F1,
  !.
%orderedInsert(nodo(S, ListaAzioniPerS, C, S),
%              [nodo(S1, ListaAzioniPerS1, C1, S1)|Rest],
%       [nodo(S, ListaAzioniPerS, C, S), nodo(S1, ListaAzioniPerS1, C1, S1)|Rest]) :-
%  F is C + S,
%  F1 is C1 + S1,
%  F == F1,
%  C < C1,
%  !.
orderedInsert(X, [Y|Rest0], [Y|Rest]) :-
  orderedInsert(X, Rest0, Rest).
```

(there is a commented part that takes in exam the case where `F==F1` and so it would them order by `C`, but since I'm already messed up i just commented it)

Now, for some reason even if i call `orderedInsert/3` with the second parameter a nonempty list, it matches only with the first functor! 
But that's not all, the result is always an append at the end of the list...
Here a simple example from this line `orderedInsert(nodo(nodo1, listaAzioniPerS, 1, 1), [nodo(nodo2, listaAzioniPerS1, 2, 1)], X).`

```
[trace] 7 ?- orderedInsert(nodo(nodo1, listaAzioniPerS, 1, 1), [nodo(nodo2, listaAzioniPerS1, 2, 1)], X).
 * Call: (8) orderedInsert(nodo(nodo1, listaAzioniPerS, 1, 1), [nodo(nodo2, listaAzioniPerS1, 2, 1)], _2026) ? creep
   Call: (9) length([nodo(nodo2, listaAzioniPerS1, 2, 1)], 0) ? creep
   Fail: (9) length([nodo(nodo2, listaAzioniPerS1, 2, 1)], 0) ? creep
 * Redo: (8) orderedInsert(nodo(nodo1, listaAzioniPerS, 1, 1), [nodo(nodo2, listaAzioniPerS1, 2, 1)], _2026) ? creep
 * Call: (9) orderedInsert(nodo(nodo1, listaAzioniPerS, 1, 1), [], _2278) ? creep
   Call: (10) length([], 0) ? creep
   Exit: (10) length([], 0) ? creep
 * Exit: (9) orderedInsert(nodo(nodo1, listaAzioniPerS, 1, 1), [], [nodo(nodo1, listaAzioniPerS, 1, 1)]) ? creep
 * Exit: (8) orderedInsert(nodo(nodo1, listaAzioniPerS, 1, 1), [nodo(nodo2, listaAzioniPerS1, 2, 1)], [nodo(nodo2, listaAzioniPerS1, 2, 1), nodo(nodo1, listaAzioniPerS, 1, 1)]) ? creep
X = [nodo(nodo2, listaAzioniPerS1, 2, 1), nodo(nodo1, listaAzioniPerS, 1, 1)] .
```

Tracing though the execution did not helped me at all (actually it made me wonder if I have understood prolog at all). 
Any idea where I'm wrong?

Using SWI Prolog.

Comment: The query `?- orderedInsert(nodo(nodo1, listaAzioniPerS, 1, 1), [nodo(nodo2, listaAzioniPerS1, 2, 1)], X).` does not unify with any predicate you wrote (i.e. it fails)... Saluti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the duplicated usage of variables S and S1.
You can change them - for instance - to

```
orderedInsert(nodo(N, ListaAzioniPerS, C, S),
              [nodo(N1, ListaAzioniPerS1, C1, S1)|Rest],
              [nodo(N, ListaAzioniPerS, C, S), nodo(N1, ListaAzioniPerS1, C1, S1)|Rest]) :-
  F is C + S,
  F1 is C1 + S1,
  F < F1,
  !.
```

and your code will work. BTW, you can reduce a bit the clutter:

```
orderedInsert(nodo(N, ListaAzioniPerS, C, S),
              [nodo(N1, ListaAzioniPerS1, C1, S1)|Rest],
              [nodo(N, ListaAzioniPerS, C, S), nodo(N1, ListaAzioniPerS1, C1, S1)|Rest]) :-
  C + S < C1 + S1,
  !.
```